# fullPage.js scroll to fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I have a page with a horizontal navigation on top and above that is a header img. I'm using fullPage.js as my layout and by default navbar is always on top. I want my header img to appear only on the first section and be hidden everywhere else. I was thinking about a solution in jQuery which would be if I'm on every section but first header margin-top would be `[header_img_height]` and when I get to section one it would return to `margin-top:0px`.

My header markup right now:

```
<header>
  <div id="header_banner">
  </div>
  <ul id="nav_cont">
     <li data-menuanchor="section1">
        <a id="home_hover" href="#section1">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li data-menuanchor="section2">
        <a id="about_hover" href="#section2/1">About</a>
     </li>
     <li data-menuanchor="section3">
        <a id="gallery_hover" href="#section3">Gallery</a>
     </li>
     <li data-menuanchor="section4">
        <a id="literature_hover" href="#section4">Literature</a>
     </li>
     <li data-menuanchor="section5">
        <a id="contact_hover" href="#section5">Contact</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="Home">
     <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
other sections
```

This is what I want to end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to do it with CSS directly.
Check out [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M) in which you can see how to use the class added to the `body` element to fire your own CSS changes.

Otherwise, you can also do it using callbacks such as [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) or [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction). You have an example of it available [in the fullpage.js files](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/callbacks.html).

You even have an example of how to use them in [this Apple demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html) also available [in the files to download](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/apple.html).

Answer (score -1):

Would this help? On the first section it adds the class fixed-header to your nav, and on the other sections it will disappear

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
var section1 = $('#home').offset().top;
var section2 = $('#section2').offset().top;
if($(this).scrollTop()>=section1){
$('#nav_cont').addClass('fixed-header');
}
if($(this).scrollTop()>=section2){
$('#nav_cont').removeClass('fixed-header');
}
});
});
```

Comment: I would like for my navigation to stay on top and stay fixed and that my header image is hidden on all the sections but first where i'd like my header image to appear.

Comment: fullpage.js default behavior won't fire the scroll event.